# multiple modules using before_body_end

Tags: layout

I created a module that uses the "before_body_end". On some pages a second module also uses before_body_end. Is there a way to dermine the order ?

example:

```
<div class='mymodule'></div>
<div class='3rdpartymodule'></div>
</body>
```

to :

```
<div class='3rdpartymodule'></div>
<div class='mymodule'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An addendum to @marius' answer, rather than place the core dependency in a core override you can state the dependency in your own module so that disabling it also disables the dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_YourModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </YourCompany_YourModule>
        <Mage_Customer>
            <depends>
                <YourCompany_YourModule/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 6):

in the layout XML of your extension add the `after` attribute to the block declaration.

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
   <block type="your/module" name="your_module" after="-" template="your/module.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

As long as the other extension doesn't do the same you should be good and your block should always be inserted last.

Answer (score 5):

Make you module depend on the third party module. Add this in `app/etc/modules/[Namespace]_[Module].xml`

```
<depends>
    <Thirdparty_Module />
</depends>
```

Comment: Looks a bit like a hack. It would also mean that the third party module can't be disabled.

Comment: Not a hack. A workaround. See my answer for an addendum to this method, @Fran

Comment: This is not actually a hack. It's a feature :). If you don't like this approach you can try what @SanderMangel posted. I don't know how I didn't thing of that. It's kind of obvious.

Comment: Sorry but this is a dirty solution. @Sander provided the right answer there. Your solution would imply the first module DEPENDS on the other one, which is absolutely not true. Not saying it's not going to work, it's just not a very clean way to achieve it.

Comment: @Fran I totally agree with you on this.